# Add a static Thank You page on form submit using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

New to Rails but having difficulty getting this thank you page to load.

Problem: A website visitor can fill out the contact us form on my site, then get routed to a generic Thank You page. However, when the form is submitted, a '/thank-you' page loads 'mysite.com/thank-you' and all that renders is the navbar.

I'd like it so when a visitor fills out the form, they are routed to the thank-you page without the navbar, but just a 'message sent' text with an exit button.

Contact form controller:

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

    if @contact.deliver
      # flash[:notice] = "Your message has been sent!"
      redirect_to thank_you_path(@contact)
    else
      redirect_to root_path, flash: { alert: "Try again. Error sending message." }
    end
  end

  private

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :message)
  end
end
```

thank-you page controller:

```
class ThankYouController < ApplicationController
  def show
  end
end
```

pages controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @contact = Contact.new
  end
end
```

thank-you.html.erb

```
<h1>your message has been sent</h1>
<a href="www.google.com">Exit</a>
```

```
routes.rb

    Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :contact, only: [:create]
  root to: "pages#home"

  get 'thank-you', to: 'thank_you#show'
end
```

When the 'thank-you' page is rendered after the form is submitted, this is what loads, see attached imaged.
[image]

When I refresh this thank-you page a second time, the page refreshes and only the navbar is rendered.

---

After creating the thank_you page controller, checking the routes, and writing a quick and dirty thank you -- nothing seems to link up.

I don't want to use a flash message here. Prefer to use the landing page as I want to add more content to this page at a later date.

Also, the user does not need to log in to complete the contact form.

**UPDATE:** I UPDATED THE CONTACT CONTROLLER TO RENDER FLASH MSG INSTEAD (DOES NOT WORK):

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.deliver
      flash.now[:notice] = 'Message sent!'
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Try again. Error sending message."
      render 'pages/home'
    end
  end

  private

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :message)
  end
end
```

Once the form is submitted, there isn't a page reload so the flash message does not appear. If i refresh the page, the flash notice renders but does not disappear.

```
Error from Chrome Developer Tools after I submit the form.
```

[image]

Comment: What does your `config/routes.rb` for the `ThankYouController` look like? How is the thank-you pages view file named and in what folder does it life?

Comment: @spickermann I've updated the post to include the routes.rb code. The thankyou page in the view is as follows:

views (folder) -> thank_you (folder) ->show.html.erb

Comment: @max thanks for providing this information. I went ahead and updated the contact_controller with your code, but this also didn't work. I created a 'thank_you.html.erb' file in the views/contact folder. Then updated the routes.rb file to reflect this change: get 'thank_you', to: 'contact#thank_you' but this doesn't render anything once the form is submitted.

Comment: @max even if i revert to just have a flash message pop-up, the flash message only shows when I refresh the page myself. The flash message doesn't pop up after I submit the form.

Comment: Is the contact created when you submit the form?

Comment: Yep, the contact is created. I receive the email with the form details.

Comment: What is actually returned by the web server to the browser? What is the status code of that POST request and what does its body look like?

Comment: On submitting the form again, what is returned in the browser is the screenshot i've added above (the one that has 2023), but without the 'thank-you' prefix as I switched to a flash message; notice in this case. This is the POST status code:

| Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:3000/
19:10:44 web.1  | Completed 302 Found in 5245ms

Comment: I am sorry, when I wasn't clear. I wonder how the request and response looked like in the for example, Google Chrome developer tools in the client? The pure HTTP headers and body that went over the wire. Not what the browser rendered.

Comment: @spickermann, no worries. I've addd a screenshot of the 400 error message from Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: Looks like you have turbo on your form enabled. Remove it to make the redirect work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved. The issue was a line of JS code that was conflicting with the redirect. After tweaking the code, the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to actually redirect after a successful form submission - you can also just render a response that confirms that the action was successful. So having a separate controller and route is overkill.

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.deliver
      render :thank_you # you could also just use the implicit create.html.erb
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Try again. Error sending message."
      render 'pages/home'
    end
  end

  private

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :message)
  end
end
```

Then there are the naming issues. In rails `resources` should be plural - `resources :contacts` since it represents the noun and not the verb. The names of files and pretty much everything in Rails should be `snake_case` and not dasherized (`thank_you.html.erb` not `thank-you.html.erb`).

Also **do not** redirect on a failed form submission. This will lead to the loss of all the user input and they won't be happy if they have to re-enter all the data and will find some place else to spend their money.

When implementing a contact form it can be good to actually save the data into the database instead of just sending an email alone. That gives you some resilience against delivery failure and can let you automatically try to resend the email.